# What's the idiomatic way to do a map/getOrElse returning Unit in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What's the most idiomatic way to do a side-effect if a value is Some(...) and do another side-effect if a value is None. Here's what I'd currently tend to write:

```
def doSideEffectA(value: Int) {
  // ...
}

def doSideEffectB() {
  // ...
}

def doSideEffect(valueOption: Option[Int]) {
  valueOption map { value =>
    doSideEffectA(value)
  } getOrElse {
    doSideEffectB()
  }
}
```

My problem is that if I didn't have to do anything if valueOption is None, here's what I'd write:

```
def doSideEffectNothingIfNone(valueOption: Option[Int]) {
  valueOption foreach { value =>
    doSideEffectA(value)
  }
}
```

map/getOrElse are usually not used in a side-effect context, while foreach is. I'm not really comfortable with valueOption map { ... } getOrElse { ... } returning Unit, as I don't really "get" anything from my Option[Int].

Comment: what is wrong with pattern matching?

Comment: Nothing. Except that, for boolean patterns, it's a bit verbose. With Option, I intuitively tend to stick with map/getOrElse and foreach. I guess I'd like to write something like the following: valueOption foreach { ... } "orDoThis" { ... }, to extend the existing foreach pattern.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What Kim Stebel said: pattern matching is a simple solution.

```
valueOption match {
  case Some(value) => doSideEffectA(value)
  case None => doSideEffectB()
}
```

Comment: It's probably the most idiomatic way to do what I want, at least in Scala 2.9, but it feels a bit like using pattern matching (value match { case true => ... ; case false => ... ; }) instead of if (value) { ... } else { ... }.

Comment: @OlivierBruchez You could use `if (value) { ... } else { ... }` if `doSideEffectA` doesn't need to extract anything from the `Some`. That's the difference between pattern matching and simple conditionals; it both checks that the pattern matches **and** extracts some data.

Answer (score 9):

Scala 2.10 includes a `fold` method on `Option` which is suitable for any case where you need both `None` and `Some` to resolve to the same type (including `Unit`):

```
scala> Option("salmon").fold(println("No fish")){f => println(s"I like $f")}
I like salmon
```

Answer (score 4):

With scalaz you get a `fold` method on `Option`, that takes two functions and executes one of them depending on whether you have a `Some` or a `None`:

```
scala> some(3).fold({ x => println(x) }, println("FOO"))
3

scala> none[String].fold({ x => println(x) }, println("FOO"))
FOO
```

Answer (score 4):

[Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) has `cata`, which would allow you to state it like this:

```
valueOption.cata(doSideEffectA, doSideEffectB)
```

Never used it, but it looks pretty useful and readable to me. This is how it's implemented:

```
  /**
   * Catamorphism over the option. Returns the provided function `some` applied to item contained in the Option
   * if it is defined, otherwise, the provided value `none`.
   */
  def cata[X](some: A => X, none: => X): X = value match {
    case None => none
    case Some(a) => some(a)
  }
```

Comment: And scala 2.10 has .fold btw

Comment: I think *that* will eventually be the most idiomatic way.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the fact that I still think pattern matching is the most readable option, you can also have it your way and define a wrapper around `Option` with an implicit conversion.

```
class Else(doit:Boolean) {
  def orDoThis[A](f: =>A) {
    if (doit) f
  }
}

class OptionWrapper[A](o:Option[A]) {
  def each[B](f: A=>B):Else = o match {
    case Some(v) => f(v); new Else(false)
    case None => new Else(true)
  }
}

implicit def wrapOption[A](o:Option[A]):OptionWrapper[A] = new OptionWrapper(o)
```

Then you can write for example:

```
Some(1) each println orDoThis println("nothing there")
```

Answer (score 1):

The *most* idiomatic way really is pattern matching. Otherwise, you can create an implicit wrapper which provides the desired method:

```
class RichOption[T](o: Option[T]) {
  def ifEmpty(action: => Unit) { if (o.isEmpty) action }
}

object RichOption {
  implicit def enrich(o: Option[T]) = return new RichOption(o)
}
```

EDIT: the one in @KimStebel's answer better matches the desired usage.